# JMeter: Need longer session life than header life span

Tags: session, jmeter, request-headers

I have a SimpleController, containing an HTTPCookieManager, an HTTPHeaderManager and two HTTPRequests that need to be in the same session. The first request works fine, the second less so - it doesn't reproduce the behavior in the browser.

Now, looking into Browser-Server communication, I see that the two requests have different Accept and Content-Type request header.

Since JMeter 2.3.2, several HTTP Header Managers are allowed ( http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager ) , I use 2.7, so I added one into the SimpleController, between the two requests, to no recognizable effect; the header for the request is not changed. I seem to misunderstand the documentation.

How do I create HTTP Requests with different request headers in one Simple Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configs are sampler or controller-specific, try adding it as a child rather than in-between.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some more googling did it. Sorry.

This helped by providing a running example:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager

So it seems that only the first Header manager is used inside a Simple Controller; so to use another header, just add another Simple Controller inside the original one, only then the new Header Controller is actually used.

```
Simple Controller
  Header Controller
  Request 1 (creates session)
  Simple Controller (new scope)
    Header Controller (adapts the header for this scope)
    Request 2
```